# Is there a color mixing/blend tool in blender Grease Pencil?

Tags: grease-pencil

I wish to know if there is a color mixing/blend tool in Blender Grease Pencil? Or even if there is a just a tool that helps make transition between colors easier. Is there anything Blender like I described?